# Identification of snake

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

Can someone identify this snake? Photographed in a home in Los Lunas, NM, USA.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Desert Kingsnake (*Lampropeltis getula splendida*).  It is native to New Mexico.

[image]

Source: [Desert Kingsnake (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desert_kingsnake)